# A common zero for a homogeneous polynomial and its gradient implies the existence of a common non-constant factor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, polynomials, algebraic-curves

Good morning,

I've recently came across the following question: let $n\ge 2$ and $P\in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ be an homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$.

Let $v$ be a real projective common zero of $P$ and $\partial_{x_i}P$ for $i=1,\dots,n$, i.e. $v$ is a real projective common zero for $n+1$ homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, one of degree $d$ and the others of degree $d-1$.

My question is the following: does this imply that $P,\partial_{x_1}P,\dots,\partial_{x_n}P$ have a non-constant common factor $P_c\in \mathbb{R}[X_1,\dots,x_n]$ of some degree $1\le k\le d$?

Using the classical theory of Resultants (see e.g. Theorem A [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-054-01/S0002-9939-1976-0387256-5/S0002-9939-1976-0387256-5.pdf)) I've convinced myself that this is true if $n=2$, and moreover if 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_{x_1}P(x_1,x_2)&= P_c(x_1,x_2)^k Q_1(x_1,x_2),\\
\partial_{x_2}P(x_1,x_2)&= P_c(x_1,x_2)^k Q_2(x_1,x_2),
\end{aligned}
$$
then by the Euler formula $dP(x_1,x_2)=x_1\partial_{x_1}P(x_1,x_2)+x_2\partial_{x_2}P(x_1,x_2)$ then it should be true that $$P(x_1,x_2)=P_c(x_1,x_2)^{k+1}R(x_1,x_2).$$

Also, I'm aware that there is a multivariate version of the resultant, which I believe should answer my question, but unfortunately I have not been able to find (or to understand) such a result in the literature.

Could you please indicate if my intuition is true and to point out relevant results of this kind in the literature? Or maybe prove me wrong, providing a counterexample?

Many thanks in advance. Bests

Comment: The condition just says that $P=0$ is singular. Try $P=x^2y-z^3$ in three variables.